# unable to display video in jsp and spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, html5-video

I am trying to display video from spring mvc.
but video is not displaying in jsp. "images" is already configured in servlet dipacher xml.

```
<c:set value="${fn:split('fName','.')}" var="separatorPosition" />
<c:set value="${separatorPosition[fn:length(separatorPosition)-1]}" var="vidType" />

<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="530" height="264"
poster="<c:url value="/resources/images/music.png"></c:url>"
data-setup="{}"> 
<source src="<c:url value="/images/${post.filePath}"></c:url>" type='video/${vidType}'>
<p class="vjs-no-js">                                               To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a    href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p></video>
```

Comment: have you checked the value of `<c:url value="/images/${post.filePath}">`? try opening it directly in  your browser and see if it loads there or what's the status code.

Comment: i sovled it. issue was video type